# Trying to speed up python code by replacing loops with functions

Tags: python, performance, function, loops

I am trying to come up with a faster way of coding what I want to. Here is the part of my program I am trying to speed up, hopefully using more inbuilt functions:

```
num = 0
num1 = 0
rand1 = rand_pos[0:10]
time1 = time.clock() 
for rand in rand1:   
     for gal in gal_pos:
         num1 = dist(gal, rand)
         num = num + num1 
time2 = time.clock()
time_elap = time2-time1
print time_elap
```

Here, rand_pos and gal_pos are lists of length 900 and 1 million respectively.
Here dist is function where I calculate the distance between two points in euclidean space.
I used a snippet of the rand_pos to get a time measurement.
My time measurements are coming to be about 125 seconds. This is way too long!
It means that if I run the code over all the rand_pos, it will take about three hours to do!
Is there a faster way I can do this?

Here is the dist function:

```
def dist(pos1,pos2):
    n = 0
    dist_x = pos1[0]-pos2[0]
    dist_y = pos1[1]-pos2[1]
    dist_z = pos1[2]-pos2[2]
    if dist_x<radius and dist_y<radius and dist_z<radius:
        positions = [pos1,pos2]
        distance = scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(positions, metric = 'euclidean')
        if distance<radius:
            n = 1       
return n
```

Comment: Probably, but post the actual code, and run a [profiler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) to see what's causing the bottleneck. It's almost certainly your implementation of `dist` that's to blame.

Comment: [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html)

Comment: we cannot see dist, which could be important

Comment: I just added dist function @user3125280

Comment: I am already using pdist @BrenBarn

Comment: @AbhinavKumar: Instead of just running pdist on one pair at a time, you should pass it (or cdist) your entire set of points and let it do the looping.

Comment: @BrenBarn doing pdist or cdist would pair numbers from the two lists right? For example if I had a = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]] and b = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]]. Running pdist or cdist over them would give me 0 for two pairs (element 1 of both lists, and element 2 of both lists).

Comment: @AbhinavKumar: No, it computes all pairwise distances, not just corresponding ones.  The lists don't even have to be the same length.  See the documentation.  (pdist computes distances between all pairs in one list, cdist takes two lists and computes all pairs with one element from each list.)

Answer (score 3):

While most of the optimization probably needs to happen within your `dist` function, there are some tips here to speed things up:

```
# Don't manually sum
for rand in rand1:
    num += sum([dist(gal, rand) for gal in gal_pos])


#If you can vectorize something, then do
import numpy as np
new_dist = np.vectorize(dist)
for rand in rand1:
    num += np.sum(new_dist(gal_pos, rand))

# use already-built code whenever possible (as already suggested)
scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(gal, rand1, metric='euclidean')
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a function in `scipy` that does exactly what you want to do here:

```
scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(gal, rand1, metric='euclidean')
```

It will be faster than anything you write in pure `Python` probably, since the heavy lifting (looping over the pairwise combinations between arrays) is implemented in `C`.

Currently your loop is happening in Python, which means there is more overhead per iteration, then you are making many calls to `pdist`. Even though `pdist` is very optimized, the overhead of making so many calls to it slows down your code. This type of performance issue was once described to me with a very useful analogy: its like trying to have a conversation with someone over the phone by saying one word per phone call, even though each word is going across the line very fast, your conversation will take a long time because you need to hang up and dial again repeatedly.

Comment: The analogy with a phone conversation is absolutely fantastic! Anyways, cdist accepts 2 dimensional arrays. My lists are in the following form: rand1 = [[1,2,3],[34,23,43],[23,34,23],[56,34,12]...[]]. Here each sublist includes the x,y and z position of a point. I do not know how this can be expressed as a 2D array.

Comment: I know, I wish I could take credit for it! RE your question, sure it can! just use `arr = numpy.array(rand1)`